# iOS 8 UIWebview Delegate: WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview, webkit

Sometimes my App works fine but sometimes it fails with this error:

> *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate:  *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]

I have found some other Questions about exceptions in WebKit but no one with the `NSRangeException`.

My Code:

```
- (id) init {
   myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
   myWebView.delegate = self;
   [myWebView stopLoading];
   return self;
}

- (void)loadUrl:(NSString *)urlAddress  {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [myWebView stopLoading];
   [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

}

 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    if (!myWebView.isLoading) {
        [myWebView stopLoading];
        if (selectedInfo == LOADTable) {

            NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]];
            [myWebView stopLoading];
            [self parseTable:html];

        } 

    }
 }
```

Do anybody have an idea how to solve this error.

The `UIWebView` is not shown on any `UIView`. Just for loading the HTML.

Comment: please use exception breakpoint to find exact linke for your crash , another help is : please use strong references for your UIWebView and finally please dont call stop loading in init method

Comment: @MohamadFarhand: Thanks for the hint with the `Exception breakpoint`. Solved it to find the exact Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please post the code of `parseTable:` method. Also, before calling `parseTable:` method, please ensure you put a nil check on your html string. And inside `parseTable:` method, please make sure you are putting safe check on NSArray count before calling `objectAtIndex:` method on it. Looks like you are trying to access 7th item (index 6) from NSArray which contains only 6 items (max index 5).

Comment: It was my fault in `parseTable:`. I will accept your Answer due to the best explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the crash occures in [self parseTable:html]; so check breakpoint to this line and confirm. if it is true then debug inside this method